# Crear labels variables en función de un valor dado

Tags: python, tkinter, ventana, label

Os vengo a consultar un problema de optimización que me he encontrado. Lo que quiero con este mini programita es que el usuario meta un valor por una pantalla que he creado y a partir del número que el usuario admita, en un rango determinado, este me un número diferente de labels en otra pantalla.

Para ello he realizado una concatenación de condicionales if, pero entiendo que esa no es la forma más óptima y que además limita mucho el número que voy a poder meter, ya que si necesito añadir más tengo que alargar el código más y más, por lo que me gustaría que me pudierais indicar como hacer esto de una forma de la cual pueda realizarlo sin llenarlo todo de estos condicionales.

Muchas gracias por adelantado y un saludo!

```
from tkinter import *

raiz= Tk()
raiz.config(width="500", height ="200")
salida=['S1','S2','S3','S4','S5','S6']
numero_asignaciones_salida=Label(raiz,text="Selecciona el numero de salidas asignadas")
numero_asignaciones_salida.place(x=50, y=60)
entry_salidas=Entry(raiz)
entry_salidas.place(x=290, y=60)
boton=Button(raiz, text="Siguiente",command=lambda:[asignasalidas(entry_salidas.get())])
boton.place(x=225,y=125)

def asignasalidas(num):
    global salida
    ventana=Toplevel(raiz)
    ventana.config(width="500", height ="200")
    salida1_label=Label(ventana,text=f"la salida asignada es {salida[0]}")
    salida2_label=Label(ventana,text=f"la salida asignada es {salida[1]}")
    salida3_label=Label(ventana,text=f"la salida asignada es {salida[2]}")
    salida4_label=Label(ventana,text=f"la salida asignada es {salida[3]}")
    salida5_label=Label(ventana,text=f"la salida asignada es {salida[4]}")
    salida6_label=Label(ventana,text=f"la salida asignada es {salida[5]}")
    error_label=Label(ventana,text="ERROR, solo se puede seleccionar un número del 1 al 6")
    if (int(num)==1):
        salida1_label.place(x=100,y=25)
    elif (int(num)==2):
        salida1_label.place(x=100,y=25)
        salida2_label.place(x=100,y=50)
    elif (int(num)==3):
        salida1_label.place(x=100,y=25)
        salida2_label.place(x=100,y=50)
        salida3_label.place(x=100,y=75)
    elif (int(num)==4):
        salida1_label.place(x=100,y=25)
        salida2_label.place(x=100,y=50)
        salida3_label.place(x=100,y=75)
        salida4_label.place(x=100,y=100)
    elif (int(num)==5):
        salida1_label.place(x=100,y=25)
        salida2_label.place(x=100,y=50)
        salida3_label.place(x=100,y=75)
        salida4_label.place(x=100,y=100)
        salida5_label.place(x=100,y=125)
    elif (int(num)==6):
        salida1_label.place(x=100,y=25)
        salida2_label.place(x=100,y=50)
        salida3_label.place(x=100,y=75)
        salida4_label.place(x=100,y=100)
        salida5_label.place(x=100,y=125)
        salida6_label.place(x=100,y=150)
    else:
        error_label.place(x=100,y=100)
        
raiz.mainloop()
```

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con un `for i in range(num)`... y calcular las posiciones de "X" y "Y", pero por lo que veo solo cambia "Y"

Comment: Pero yo no quiero tener predefinidos todos los labesl, sino que según el número que el usuario introduzca, se creen más o menos. Eso se puede hacer?

Comment: Es lo mismo, cuando el usuario ingresa N datos los puedes asignar a una lista, luego con el `for` creas las etiquetas usando la información introducida  y así te evitas todos los `if`

Comment: Te importaría ponérmelo en una respuesta? Por que no lo termino de ver claro y me lleva a que programo algo con errores.

Comment: Voy de camino a casa, dame 10-15 min y redacto una respuesta

Comment: Cuando tú puedas por Dios! Perdona si parece que te he metido presión, nada más lejos de la realidad. Cuando puedas :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Como te puse en el comentario, podrías crear un `for` para generar el número total de etiquetas, otra forma sería utilizando comprensión de listas. He decidido mostrar el ejemplo con comprensión de listas para que sea mas "Pythonico"

Antes que nada, en tu pregunta no aclaras la razón por la  que utilizas una variable global `salida` con las etiquetas que vas a utilizar, por lo que quité la variable global del ejemplo, si necesitas utilizar las etiquetas en algún otro lado entonces tendrás que crear la variable global una vez más

Agregué un campo para que el usuario pueda configurar el prefijo que desea mostrar para las etiquetas:

```
prefijo_salida = Label(raiz,text = "Configura el prefijo de las salidas")
prefijo_salida.place(x = 50, y = 90)
entry_prefijo = Entry(raiz)
entry_prefijo.place(x = 290, y = 90)
```

Por ejemplo, si el usuario selecciona "S" entonces las salidas serán "S1", "S2", ... , "SN". Pero si utiliza prefijo "do" entonces las salidas serán "do1", "do2", ... ,"doN". Si deseas utilizar un prefijo fijo entonces puedes eliminar esa sección y crear una variable `prefijo` con el `string` que siempre vas a utilizar. Este variable `entry_prefijo` ahora es un argumento más de la función para crear las etiquetas.

```
def asignasalidas(num, pre):
```

Dentro de la función donde se crean las etiquetas creamos una lista con tantas etiquetas como haya recibido el argumento `num` con una comprensión de listas

```
salida_label = [Label(ventana, text = f'La salida asignada es {pre}{x+1}') for x in range(int(num))]
```

Y para configurar la posición de las etiquetas utilizamos otra comprensión de listas, nota que únicamente se modifica el valor de "y".

```
salida1_label = [x.place(x = 100, y = (25 * (i + 1))) for i, x in enumerate(salida_label)]
```

Como en tu ejemplo el espaciamiento vertical es `25` entonces utilizo la fórmula `(25 * (i + 1)))` para asignar la posición de las etiquetas en "y", la variable `i` va a ir de 0 a N-1, por lo que es necesario sumar 1 para que muestre la etiqueta correcta

Ejemplo completo:

```
from tkinter import *

raiz = Tk()
raiz.config(width = "500", height = "200")

numero_asignaciones_salida = Label(raiz,text = "Selecciona el numero de salidas asignadas")
numero_asignaciones_salida.place(x = 50, y = 60)
entry_salidas = Entry(raiz)
entry_salidas.place(x = 290, y = 60)

prefijo_salida = Label(raiz,text = "Configura el prefijo de las salidas")
prefijo_salida.place(x = 50, y = 90)
entry_prefijo = Entry(raiz)
entry_prefijo.place(x = 290, y = 90)

boton = Button(raiz, text = "Siguiente", command = lambda: [asignasalidas(entry_salidas.get(), entry_prefijo.get())])
boton.place(x = 225, y = 125)

def asignasalidas(num, pre):
    ventana = Toplevel(raiz)
    ventana.config(width = "500", height = "200")
    
    salida_label = [Label(ventana, text = f'La salida asignada es {pre}{x+1}') for x in range(int(num))]
    
    salida1_label = [x.place(x = 100, y = (25 * (i + 1))) for i, x in enumerate(salida_label)]
        
raiz.mainloop()
```

Comment: Buah muchas gracias! es justo lo que necesitaba y funciona perfectamente. De verdad muchísimas gracias!

Comment: No hay de qué, saludos!

Comment: No se si sea más Pythonico o no, pero no me parece buena idea usar comprensión de listas con place, ya que este método siempre devuelve None.

Comment: Buen punto, más que nada lo hice para recorrer la lista y generar las posiciones, tal vez sea mejor reemplazar la segunda comprensión de listas por un `for`